# TSQL Like query in an "in" query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I have a query like the following:

```
select * from table1 where desc in (select field1 from table2)
```

here is the kicker though.  I want all the values in the "in" query to be likes. Sort of like the following:

```
select * from table1 where (desc like field1 + '%" or  desc like field1b + '%')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but it should work.....

```
select t1.* from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.desc like t2.field1 + '%'
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  I didn't think of using the join.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this, but on first glance a semi-join should work:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where exists (
  select 1
  from table2 t2
  where
    left (t1.desc, len (t2.field1)) = t2.field1
)
```

Comment: +1 as won't bring back duplicates if multiple match. `like` can make better use of indexes though.